# Make a condition with restrictions Java

Tags: java

Have a task on my education in Java:
Make a condition, which is true if only one of X and Z values is less than 20.
The way how to do that is like:

```
(X < 20 && Y >= 20) || (X >= 20 && Y < 20)
```

Or

```
(a < 20) != (b < 20)
```

But I have restrictions, it should be solved using no more than 2 comparison operators, no * / + - operators, no bitwise operators

Comment: Please check the list of [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Is there any operator which could be handy for exclusive conditions? We can trivially answer this, but try to find the answer yourself.

Comment: Next time please specify the *complete* condition *before* people start answering your question. Substantially modifying the question (like you did) after there are several answers there is not a good thing to do and deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return Math.max(a, b) >= 20 && Math.min(a, b) < 20;
```

Comment: Arithmetic operators are prohibited.

Comment: -400 and 21 would create a false negative

Comment: `Math.max` and `Math.min` both use one comparison, that will be 3.

Comment: if both values are 20 max is 20 so the first condition is true, min is 20 so the second condition is false, so it works... @Lino

Comment: we want to check if only one is less than 20, if a = 20 and b = 20 as you said we have true && false that return false, but this is what we want... the question is: is only one less than 20? No, they are both 20 so we're expecting a false and this is what we have @Lino

Comment: @GJCode, i retract, you are completly right. Still early brain is not functioning as good ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can use XOR operator `^`

```
if( (x < 20) ^ (z < 20) )
```

Comment: it's a bitwise one, which is not allowed

Comment: @ArtyomShakhov this isn't a bitwise `^`, it is a [Boolean logical `^`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, but a bitwise as well, on Oracle's tutorials, Schildt's reference

Answer (score 4):

By using the conditional operator `? :` you can achieve that:

```
if(X < 20 ? Y >= 20 : Y < 20){
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but 3 comparison operators

Answer (score 2):

[Lino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178257/3788176) was

```
if(X < 20 ? Y >= 20 : Y < 20){
```

And apparently that uses too many comparison operators. So, rewrite it with just 2:

```
boolean b = Y >= 20;
if (X < 20 ? b : !b) {
```

Comment: So simple, but I didn't even thought of that :)

Answer (score -3):

You just have to check if one of the values is less than 20. This should work:

`if( x < 20 || y < 20){
...
}`

Comment: If only one is less than 20. What if x=10 and y=10